# How can i load Google Analytics in time to capture the UTM tracking code before SharePoint's vanity url redirects to the destination URL?

Tags: google-analytics

Non-Dev or IT here, I had a client who is using Sharepoint's vanity URL feature. Problem is that that the 302 redirect loads before Google Analytics can load and so I'm losing UTM tracking or any other kind of tracking code attached to the URL.

What options do I have here?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using and are you using Alternate Access Mapping, extensions, IIS? I need a bit more information about the implementation you are using.

Comment: @AneudyM we are using Sharepoint 2013. I'm unsure if we are using Alternate Access Mapping. How can we check? If we are, how will this impact our situation? 

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!